# Ubuntu showing the incorrect application title for IntelliJ

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

IntelliJ had been installed on my Ubuntu for 1 and half years now and I recently noticed that the application name of IntelliJ is a name of a project. Note that it is not the open project, it's just a random project name I had previously opened through IntelliJ. Ideally, the application title should be "IntelliJ" like every other application shows their name.

How can I fix that?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify a little bit more about what exactly your problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the file .idea/.name - the wrong name could be saved there.
the cleanest solution is to delete the .idea folder and reimport (not reopen) the project.